# Deploying a Java Azure Function to Azure Functions Runtime (On Premises)

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

So I am using Azure Functions at work and thought I would have a play and install them on my own server.  I have successfully installed Azure Functions Runtime 2 (preview).

I have then followed the Java tutorial to create an Azure Function :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-java-maven

How do I then deploy this function to my own Azure functions server?
In the guide it says about using :

- az login
- mvn azure-functions:deploy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, `mvn azure-functions:deploy` is to deploy functions to Azure site as `az login` is required before deployment, which doesn't support deployment to on-premises Runtime portal.

But the key point is, the on-premises Runtime is obsolete(one year behind the latest bits), new project probably can't work with it even if we find how to publish.

Since v2 becomes GA, it is recommended to leverage [custom image](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/azure-functions/) for usages out of Azure box.

**Update**

Missed one point. As AF Team answered in the [issue you post](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/1117#issuecomment-458372383), no Java Image for now so the usage of Azure Java Function outside Azure is blocked unless we could figure out creating the image on our own.

Comment: So it's now a dead product?  That's a shame, I will have to go to OpenFaas or FN

Comment: @Burf2000 Good choice, actually since v2 becomes GA, it is recommended to leverage custom container for usages out of Azure box.

Comment: Would you go OpenFaas or FN?

Comment: @Burf2000 Sorry I can't provide further suggestions. I have been with Azure site for some time and not familiar with these two platforms. But I think there's not so much difference in respect to the use of azure function since they are all based on container.